# Longest chord inside the intersection area of three circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I am currently working on my masters thesis in computer science and I stumbled onto a geometry problem.

My goal is to compute the length of the longest possible chord inside the intersection area of three circles.

I know the following thing about the circles:

- their radius is **r**
- **Construction:** Assume that there is a circle around a point **c** with size **r**. Then I choose two random points **v1** and **v2** inside this circle. These two points are the centers of the other two circles.

This bounds the distance between the centers of the circles:

- length(c,v1) is at most **r**
- length(c,v2) is at most **r**
- length(v1,v2) is at most **2r**

Note that the points can be the same. So some of this distances can be 0.

Therefore I will break this down into four cases:

- **Case 1:** *(all points are the same, c=v1=v2)*
  If all points are the same, the solution is trivial. The longest possible line inside a circle is the diameter.
- **Case 2:** *(two points are the same)*
  If two points are the same, I can compute the distance like this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html
- **Case 3:** *(three different points, but on a straight line)*
  If the three points form a straight line, I can compute the distance like in the 2nd case. I just ignore the point that is located in the middle.
- **Case 4:** *(the three points form a triangle)*
  If the 3 centers form a triangle there will be three intersection points A,B and C which will form a triangle, too (correct me if I am wrong).

To make things more clear lets rotate the situation without loss of generality.
Rotate the circle such that c is the topmost center.

Let A be the intersection point closest to c. B and C follow in clockwise direction.

Here is the situation:
[image: Find the longest chord inside the highlighted area]

I tried to compute these values by constructing other triangles but I just can not find any solution. In some special cases I could find the angles of the triangle(A,B,C) but that didn't help me either. Is it even possible? If not is there a way to find an upper bound for the longest chord (which is smaller than the obvious **2r**) ?

I wouldn't be so hard to write an approximation program but since I am working on a theoretical proof that does not help me.
I hope this question is not too dumb ;) I am not a mathematician.

Thanks in advance, hhllcks

Comment: Case 4 need not lead to a triangle of intersection points (make the  second and third centres almost $2r$ apart, but not all three on a line, which suggests a lower bound of $0$).  The upper bound looks like $2r$ (make the three centres very close together) though I may have misunderstood your question

Comment: You are right, thanks.
There can not be a smaller upper bound and Case 4 must be further broken down.

But the question remains: Can I find an equation that gives me the longest chord inside the intersection area?

Answer (score 0):

In case $4$, the intersection of the three circles is a convex set with vertices in $A,B,C$. Since the distance is a convex function, one of the longest chords is given by the longest side among $AB,AC,BC$. Obviously the longest chord is not necessarily unique: consider the configuration in which $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle.

Comment: I should have clarified that I am looking for the length of the longest chord.
This would be the length of the longest side of the triangle A,B,C.