# Longest chord in the intersection n disks (circle areas)

Tags: optimization, closed-form, covering-spaces

Given n disks that intersect, there is a shape in the space where they intersect. Given that, what is the longest chord, more generally longest line, that can be drawn in this space?
For n=1, this is the diameter
For n=2, the result can be found on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html)

What is the result for n>2? Bounds, estimates, and closed form equations will get you the bounty. Algorithms that don't guess can also get you the bounty. And I've already read [Longest chord inside the intersection area of three circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933603/longest-chord-inside-the-intersection-area-of-three-circles).

I'm going to use this result to find appropriate diameters for covers that are the union of an arbitrary number of circles. Specifically this can be used to estimate the Hausdorff measures and dimensions of fractals. So if you have a suggestion for doing that, I'd appreciate it. If you know exactly what I'm talking about at this point, you could suggest I use a different shape, such as a square or oval, since it would give an easier equation.

Comment: What makes you think that knowing the length of the longest chord will let you compute the diameter of the union? (A reply that doesn't convince me will not get my upvote.)

Comment: @TonyK The longest chord on a circle is equivalent to the diameter. I was extending this notation to the union of many circles. So the longest chord in this union is the diameter of the union.

Comment: @TonyK Actually, because I choose to use the Euclidean metric, they are equivalent. It's the supremum of d(x,y) d is the Euclidean metric so it's just the length of the longest line in the set.

Comment: OK. This is because the intersection of a set of circles (properly, closed disks) is always convex.

Comment: This would be well-approximated by the major axis of the Löwner-John ellipsoid, I think. If so, the question is whether or not computing that ellipsoid is tractable, or if a good approximation is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 circles there are three relevant configurations:

- no intersection/touching (max length = 0 and we are done)
- intersection in 2 points
- one circle completely inside another (in which case we just ignore the outer circle)

Adding another, N-th circle can have each of the 3 configurations with respect to all the other circles, for a total of $3^{N(N-1)/2}$ configurations with up to $N(N+1)$ intersection points. Simply determining which case you have at hand is bothersome and any analytical plug&chug formula where you just use all the center positions and radii would be ridiculously long and inefficient.

Lets use your example (positions (2,2);(-4,-4);(1,3);(3,2);(-1,-1) and the <s>diameter</s> radius of each circle is 5 (with a diameter of 5 the solution is trivial since there is no overlap)) and find the solution manually.

- we want to shrink the upper bound as fast as possible, so we compute all $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ distances between centers and pick the two circles furthest apart
- that gives us two intersection points $p_1$ and $p_2$ (at around (1,-3) and (-2,0.5)) and a lens-shaped area $A$, now compute the distance between those points and the centers of all the unused circles, find the highest distance $d_{max}$ (here, the distace between $p_2 \approx (1,-3)$ and the center at (1,3)
- if $d_{max}$ < 5 then $A$ lies entirely within the other circles without being intersected, therefore we are done. If not, which is the case here, we find the intersection of that new circle (the one around (1,3)) with the previous ones (it intersects the circles in 4 points, but we are only interested in those that lie on the perimeter of A)
- repeat the last two steps, finding the circles which are close enough to the perimeter of $A$, until the area isn't shrinking anymore. The longest line is the greatest of the distances between all the intersection points on the perimeter of $A$

If the radii are all different then it gets more complicated but the general idea is the same, and here is a sketch that will hopefully clarify what i am talking about
[image]

Comment: Seems like an effective solution, but I need clarification on steps (2) and (3).  "...find the intersection of that new circle with the previous ones (on the perimeter of the intersection, that is, closest to the other two points)" what does this mean exactly? You also mention that if, at the beginning of step 3, the radius is less than 5 we are done. Why is that exactly?

Comment: You get the bounty for real. I won't revoke it, promise. Good job, very simple method, but it really does work. Also doesn't take up to much computer power.

Comment: This is not correct as it stands, though it may be that it can be expanded to give a complete solution.  I posted an explanation and counterexample as a non-answer answer, since it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Good job, your answer solved my problem in a very simple way, which is what makes it valuable.

Answer (score 2):

The ellipsoid of maximum area that is wholly contained within the intersection of circles (indeed, ellipsoids) can be computed with convex optimization. The details of the mathematics can be found in Section 8.4.2 of [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd & Vandenberghe. Below I summarize the relevant portion of the material, simplified by the fact that your ellipsoids are all circles.

The target ellipsoid $\mathcal{E}$ is parameterized as follows:
$$\mathcal{E}=\{Bu+d\,|\,\|u\|_2\leq 1\}$$
where $B$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $d$ is a vector. Each
circle $\mathcal{C}_i$ is described by its center $v_i$ and radius $r_i$.
The maximum volume ellipsoid is the solution to the semidefinite program
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}_{\lambda,B,d} & \log\det B \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} r_i^2-\lambda_i & 0 & d^T-v_i^T \\ 0 & \lambda_i I & B \\ d - v_i & B & I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, ~ i=1,2,\dots, m
\end{array}
The optimization variables are $B$, $d$, and one $\lambda_i\geq 0$ for each circle.

It's quite possible this model can be simplified further; constraining the ellipsoids to be circles has introduced a lot of structure. I will consider this further and edit if necessary.

Once you have this ellipsoid, you could extract its major axis and use that as an approximate chord. You can improve the approximation by computing scaling it until it intersects one or more of the circles.

Comment: I read a bit about the Lowner Johns ellipsoid. It seems like it would give bounds on my problem, and many other problems in addition.

Comment: Agreed, I certainly do not want to claim that it is anything but an approximation/heuristic. And actually, this is the maximum volume *inscribed* ellipsoid that I have described here, whereas the Lowner John ellipsoid is the minimum volume *circumscribed* ellipsoid. And here's the thing: for a given problem, it is usually the case that *either* the inscribed ellipsoid is tractable, *or* the circumscribed ellipsoid is tractable, but not both. In this case, the circumscribed ellipsoid is not tractable.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the lower bound is 0, which is achievable if all circles are disjoint.

The upper bound is the smallest diameter (say circle $C$ has the smallest diameter), which is also achievable by placing all circles through a pair of antipodals of $C$.

Comment: That's a rather trivial bound...do you have anything better?

Comment: Well, those bounds are sharp (as is explained in my answer). One cannot hope for better bound.

Comment: I meant those bounds encompass every value it could be. As to your second point, if you create bounds that depend on the position and diameter of the circles the result would be non-trivial. Then the bounds would be a changing function $f(x,y,d)$. That's what I haven't had any luck with.

Comment: If the position and diameter of the circles are known, then the exact value of the longest chord is determined and there wouldn't be any bound. I am not sure what you meant by 'bounds depending on the position and diameter of circles'.

Comment: Well then if I have 5 or any number of circles positioned at 5 defined points, have to keep some generality, each with diameter 5, can you give be the diameter of the intersection region. If so, you earned the bounty. If not, that is what I'm asking for, and why I consider that bound to be trivial.

Comment: I need to know what you mean by 'keep some generality'. If those 5 circles are far apart, then they do not intersect and so its diameter is 0. On the other hand, if those 5 circles are the same, then the diameter of the intersection is 5.

Comment: That's what makes the problem non-trivial. In addition, this is what I'm asking for. I want a function that takes the positions and diameters and gives me the diameter of the intersection space. Out of curiosity if the positions are (2,2);(-4,-4);(1,3);(3,2);(-1,-1) and the diameter of each circle is 5, how would you prove the exact value of the diameter of the intersection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22505/discussion-between-roy-24601-and-zach466920).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is more difficult than just identifying the intersection region, for which the accepted answer gives an algorithm.  The issue with that answer is that the final line of the algorithm is incorrect ("the longest line is the greatest of the distances between all the intersection points on the perimeter of A").  In fact, the longest line may be between an intersection point and a point in the interior of an arc, or between two interior points.

The image below is an example of the first case: the diameter of the intersection region is equal to the diameter of the yellow circle, but no two of the three intersection points are that far apart.  To see an example of the second case, push the red circle slightly to the left; again, the diameter of intersection region will be equal to the yellow circle's diameter, but no two of the four intersection points will be that far apart.

[image]

Comment: Since I only wanted a solution for when all the circles are the same diameter, and the answer given above only deals with this case, your supposed problem only rules out generalizing this algorithm to circles of different diameters.

Comment: @Zach466920: Oh, okay... the problem didn't state that the circles were all the same size.  I think you're right that this situation can't arise in that case.

Comment: Still, thanks for the pointer. I was getting ready to generalize the algorithm to this case. Would've wasted a lot of time.